# Can I name my character 'Greyhound'?

Tags: copyright

I can understand getting sued for starting a train company called Greyhound, but I want to the alter ego of one of my characters to be Greyhound – a reference to the quickness of the canine. However, there is a bus carrier chain that has a similar name called Greyhound Lines Inc. Will I be sued by the bus company or do companies have a nominal monopoly on animals?

Answer (score 1):

The intellectual property right held by the Greyhound bus company in the name "Greyhound" falls under [trademark](/questions/tagged/trademark), not [copyright](/questions/tagged/copyright).

If you don't infringe the trademark, you *probably* won't be sued for infringing it.

Comment: And, not to put too fine a point on it, the scenario in the OP does not constitute trademark infringement.